# Angularjs how to differentiate among same value in an array of objects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add a list of products and upsell for these products (1 product may be added multiple times to cart). 
Using addProduct function i am adding product from available list to an array like this

```
$scope.addToCartData.push($scope.addproduct[id]);
```

each product further has an array of upsell products, now in another controller in which i have logic for upsell products, i am incrementing upsell product qty using the following code

```
$scope.addUpsellPro=function(pid,pos)
        {
          angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="ManagerCtrl"]')).scope().addToCartData[pos].upsellsProducts[pid].qty++;
          console.log(pos); 
        }
```

in here pid is the upsell product id and pos is the index value taken from

```
addToCartData
```

but the strange thing happen is it increments qty of upsell products for all same products.
e.g. if I have a product PRO1 in addproduct array, this product have up1 and up2 as upsells, now if I push PRO1 two times to the addToCartData array and then tries to increment qty of upsell product of PRO1 at postion 0 (first). it also update upsell products qty at postion 1 :(

**Image for duplicate upsells**
[image]

Comment: I would suggest keeping that kind of data in a service than in controllers. That way controllers in various parts of an app can call the central service to get the data, it's in one place and more manageable.

Comment: @rrd thanks for your suggestion, but I am absolutely new to angularjs and don't know a lot about it (services). can you point out something wrong in the given code?

Comment: @Haris The way you are using angular is not the best (no hard feelings :)) A must read for angular developers: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @RonDadon is right, that's a good guide to follow

Comment: Why do you say "it also update upsell products qty at postion 1"? Where do you see that?

Comment: @RonDadon yes I agree with you and thanks for the guide, will try to re-factor my code.

Comment: @OzW update my question with image of product list

Comment: in angular you have to avoid as much as you can the usage of Jquery ( expect in directive). you can replace this `angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="ManagerCtrl"]')).scope().addToCartData[pos].upsellsProducts[pid].qty++;` with this `$scope.addToCartData[pos].upsellsProducts[pid].qty++;`

Comment: @AlainIb thanks for suggestion but I can't use like this, as `addToCartData` is defined in "ManagerCtrl" controller and i cant access that contoller's scope. I will have to create service for this but right now i only want to solve the problem i am facing. :(

Comment: How are you presenting the data? Are you using `ngRepeat`? If so, perhaps you should read about `track by $index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, in my limited knowledge of angularjs, pushing array index into another array doesn't copy the array/object but assign a reference therefore when i was updating product qty on base of position it was actually updating value of `addproduct` array, not of `addToCartData`. 
so what i did to tackle this is I used `angular.copy()` function and changed my code

```
$scope.addToCartData.push($scope.addproduct[id]);
```

to

```
$scope.addToCartData.push($scope.assignProduct(id));
```

and then created assignproduct funciton like;

```
$scope.assignProduct= function(pid)
{
  var curr_product=[];
  angular.copy($scope.addproduct[pid], curr_product);
  return curr_product;
}
```